# How use "like" operation in SCCM?

Tags: sccm, wql

I want get all programs which contains this name

Adobe Flash Player 2* ActiveX

In `SCCM` i make this request

```
Select ... SMS_G_System_INSTALLED_SOFTWARE.ProductName like "Adobe Flash Player 2? ActiveX"
```

But it not return data. If i make this request

```
like "Adobe Flash Player 22 ActiveX"
```

This query normally return data.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the '?' operator is supported in WQL. Try "Adobe Flash Player 2% ActiveX" instead.

For reference:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa392263(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: That would work, but no be exactly the same imo. Is the ? normally not reservered for a single character? In that case the correct WQL equivalent would be _ (as can also be seen in the reference you linked)